# Source of <img> tag not getting updated if prop change in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, react-props

**What I am trying to do:**
I am trying to implement a "customizable" chessboard using `chessboardjsx` in a ReactJS application with the option to change pieces style. Basically I am trying to dynamically change the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag. To do that, in the example below, I click a button that change a prop that ideally should change the pieces icons.

**Where is the problem**: My problem is that even if prop is updated, `src` doesn't get updated.

**What I tried and what I've read on SO**: firstly I thought it might be a problem of browser  caching (I've read on SO a lot of question about this problem) but even implementing solution like disabling the cache, adding a key to the `img` tag or adding an hash to src didn't solve the problem. Therefore I tried to substitute the `img` tag with a `p` and writing the variable inside: prop actually did not changed, the value is always the first value assigned.

**Expected Behavior**: When I click the button, the images of the kings get swapped. (Again, this is an example, but the mechanism is the same). Here an image of the chessboard:

[image: example]

Below I present a simplified version of my code to make it more understandable.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Chessboard from "chessboardjsx";
import elvis from "../img/elvis.png";
import lebronJames from "../img/kingJames.png";
import { roughSquare } from "../customRough";

/* eslint react/display-name: 0 */
/* eslint react/prop-types: 0 */
export default function CustomizedBoard(props) {
  const [pieces, setPieces] = useState(props.pieces);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPieces(props.pieces);
  }, [props.pieces]);
  return (
    <Chessboard
      id="standard"
      orientation="black"
      width={320}
      roughSquare={roughSquare}
      position="start"
      boardStyle={{
        borderRadius: "5px",
        boxShadow: `0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`
      }}
      dropOffBoard="trash"
      pieces={{
        wK: ({ squareWidth, isDragging }) => (
          <img
            style={{
              width: isDragging ? squareWidth * 1.75 : squareWidth,
              height: isDragging ? squareWidth * 1.75 : squareWidth
            }}
            src={pieces === "a" ? elvis : lebronJames}
            alt={"elvis"}
          />
        ),
        bK: ({ squareWidth, isDragging }) => (
          <img
            style={{
              width: isDragging ? squareWidth * 1.75 : squareWidth,
              height: isDragging ? squareWidth * 1.75 : squareWidth
            }}
            src={pieces === "a" ? lebronJames : elvis}
            alt={"lebron james"}
          />
        )
      }}
      sparePieces={false}
      lightSquareStyle={{ backgroundColor: "AliceBlue" }}
      darkSquareStyle={{ backgroundColor: "CornFlowerBlue" }}
    />
  );
}
```

After reading several question on what I thought might be the problem, without any success, I thing I am not on the right path. So, what could be a solution? Or what could be the problem I come across?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
Here's the code from which I change the prop of `Chessboard`.

```
class Demo extends Component {
  state = {
    pieces: "a"
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={boardsContainer}>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ pieces: this.state.pieces === "a" ? "b" : "a" });
          }}
        >
          Change Theme
        </button>
        <CustomBoard pieces={this.state.pieces} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

Comment: Why are you using `useEffect` to call `setPieces` when you have `pieces` already as the default state? Ho are you changing the prop? Show us the code that changes the prop

Comment: FYI this will have nothing to do with caching I am willing to bet. This is most likely to do with state management.

Comment: @Dominik I added the code from which I change the prop of ```Chessboard```.  There is a mismatch between the use of class components and functional components, could it be a problem?

Comment: If `pieces` is already in state in a component that is the parent of `CustomizedBoard` then you don't need to add it into state again in `CustomizedBoard`. A state change will cause the `Demo` component to re-render and that will re-render all it's children in the tree. I suggest you log out what the prop actually is on each render and see what's going on.

Comment: @Dominik As you suggested I deleted the row const ```[pieces, setPieces] = useState(props.pieces)``` and the ```useState()``` function and logged the updated props and it changes also in the child component when I click the button. The img' src attribute still remain the same, though. Could it be a problem with the child ```Chessboard``` not being updated?

Comment: Yes, it could be that `Chessboard` is caching the images. One way to test that would be to add a `key` property to the chessboard based on the pieces property, i.e. - `<Chessboard key={props.pieces} ... />`

Comment: No problems :) -- in case you're wondering, it's working because using a different key forces the `Chessboard` to reset its state. Here's an article that describes it - https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e